# How do I get my JSON data to display in tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

I am trying to get my JSON data to display in a tableview but cant get it to work.  I have managed to display some data in text views but cannot get the data into the tableview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    final let url = URL(string: "http://**.***.**.**:*****/userconfig")

    private var users = [User]()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        downloadJSON()
    }

    func downloadJSON() {
        guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
    
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("Trouble!")
                return
        }
        print("Success!")
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedComms = try decoder.decode(Users.self, from: data)
                self.users = downloadedComms.users
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Bad!")
            }
        
        }.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommCell") as? CommCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    
        cell.nameLbl.text = users[indexPath.row].username
        cell.DOBLbl.text = users[indexPath.row].online

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the datasource on your tableView? Where do you register your cell on your tableView?

Comment: `"Bad!"` is bad, very bad. Print the `error`. **What** does not work?

Comment: `print("Bad!")` => ` print("Bad! with error: \(error)")`. Now, what's called, what's not called? What's happening exactly in your code? Did you set the delegate, the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Replace This with your `viewDidLoad` method. You didnt set your delegete and dataSource.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    downloadJSON()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your helpfull comments.  It turns out that because I was not putting all the JSON fields in my class I needed to make the ones I was including optional.

```
class Users: Codable {
let users: [User]

init(users: [User]) {
    self.users = users
}
```

}

class User: Codable {
let username: String?
let online: String?
let image: String?

```
init(username: String, online: String, image: String) {
    self.username = username
    self.online = online
    self.image = image
}
```